# Proving $|z|(|z|^{n-1}+1)<1$ with $|z|<1$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I'm trying to prove that, given a specific z such that $|z|<1$, there exists an $N$ value such that when we have $n>N$ then $|z|(|z|^{n-1}+1)<1$ .
I've done several number examples and I know it can work I'm just having trouble generalizing it. I think I'm missing something tiny. Any help would be very appreciated.

Is it just because when we have large enough $n$ then $|z|^{n-1}$ goes to zero so we have $|z|(1)$ and since $|z|<1$ the product is less than one? Or do I need to prove more?

Comment: It's false as stated. There is no $N$ that works for all $z,|z|<1.$ Rather, given such a $z,$ there exists $N$ ...

Comment: @zhw good point I will edit my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not too tricky to compute such an $N$. We have
\begin{align*}
|z|(|z|^{n - 1} + 1) < 1 &\iff |z|^{n-1} + 1 < |z|^{-1} \\
&\iff |z|^{n-1} < |z|^{-1} - 1 \\
&\iff n - 1 > \log_{|z|}(|z|^{-1} - 1) \\
&\iff n > 1 + \log_{|z|}(|z|^{-1} - 1).
\end{align*}
Note that $|z| < 1$ implies $|z|^{-1} > 1$, and so $|z|^{-1} - 1 > 0$. Also, the inequality sign reversed, as $|z| < 1$ implies $\log_{|z|}$ is a (strictly) decreasing function. So, we can simply take
$$N = 1 + \log_{|z|}(|z|^{-1} - 1),$$
or its ceiling, if you insist on $N$ being an integer.

Comment: Thank you very much! This was very helpful

Comment: The answer was excellent.